# React Native application crashes in testflight due to stack navigation issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-bottom-tab

I have a react native application. I run it on my phone and in the simulator through expo. I built it and pushed it to apple developer console and it crashes once I put it in testflight. I have no idea why the error is occuring.

When I use default and generic screens to render the bottom tab navigation with no content on it, it works and renders property. When I switch the Properties bottom tab to a stack navigation tab, my application immediately crashes on load rather than render the screen.

I have no idea why it is crashing and the logs are not helping at all. Does anyone know what is causing the issue and can help me with this issue.

Here is my code:

App.js

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, LogBox } from 'react-native';
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { onAuthStateChanged } from 'firebase/auth';
import { auth } from './src/api/firebase';

import { GeneralContextProvider } from './src/context/GeneralContext';
import { PropertyContextProvider } from './src/context/PropertyContext';
import { FilterSortContextProvider } from './src/context/FilterSortContext';
import { SinglePropertyContextProvider } from './src/context/SinglePropertyContext';
import { FinancesContextProvider } from './src/context/FinancialContext';
import { UserContextProvider } from './src/context/UserContext';
import { FeedContextProvider } from './src/context/FeedContext';
import BottomTabNavigation from './src/navigation/BottomTabNavigation';
import LoadProfile from './src/iOS/iPhone/screens/LoadProfile';

LogBox.ignoreAllLogs();

export default function App() {
  const [initializing, setInitializing] = useState(true);
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
      setUser(user);
      if (initializing) {
        setInitializing(false);
        if (user) {
          console.log(user.uid)
        }
      }
    });

    return () => unsubscribe();
  }, []);

  if (initializing) {
    return null;
  }

  return(
    <NavigationContainer style={styles.container}>
      <StatusBar 
        barStyle="dark" />
      <FeedContextProvider>
        <UserContextProvider>
          <FilterSortContextProvider>
              <FinancesContextProvider>
                <SinglePropertyContextProvider>
                  <PropertyContextProvider>
                    <GeneralContextProvider>
                      <BottomTabNavigation />
                    </GeneralContextProvider>
                  </PropertyContextProvider>
                </SinglePropertyContextProvider>
              </FinancesContextProvider>
          </FilterSortContextProvider>
        </UserContextProvider>
      </FeedContextProvider>
    </NavigationContainer>
  )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#c6c6c6',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

BottomTabNavigation.js

```
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';

import { Feather } from 'react-native-vector-icons'

import DefaultPropertiesScreen from './DefaultPropertiesScreen';
import DefaultFavoritesScreen from './DefaultFavoritesScreen';
import DefaultProfileScreen from './DefaultProfileScreen';
import DefaultFeedScreen from './DefaultFeedScreen'
import PropertiesStackNavigation from './PhoneStackNavigation/PropertiesStackNavigation';


const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

function BottomTabNavigation() {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator initialRouteName='PropertiesScreen' screenOptions={{headerShown: false}}>
      <Tab.Screen 
        name="Properties" 
        key='Properties'
        component={PropertiesStackNavigation} 
        options={{
          tabBarShowLabel: false,
          tabBarIcon: ({size, color}) => (<Feather name={"home"} color={color} size={size} />)
        }}/>
      <Tab.Screen 
        name="Favorites" 
        key='Favorites'
        component={DefaultFavoritesScreen} 
        options={{
          tabBarShowLabel: false,
          tabBarIcon: ({size, color}) => (<Feather name={"heart"} color={color} size={size} />)
        }}/>
      <Tab.Screen 
        name="Feed"
        key='Feed'
        component={DefaultFeedScreen} 
        options={{
          tabBarShowLabel: false,
          tabBarIcon: ({size, color}) => (<Feather name={"grid"} color={color} size={size} />)
        }}/>
      <Tab.Screen 
        name="Profile"
        key='Profile'
        component={DefaultProfileScreen} 
        options={{
          tabBarShowLabel: false,
          tabBarIcon: ({size, color}) => (<Feather name={"user"} color={color} size={size} />)
        }}/>
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}

export default BottomTabNavigation
```

PropertiesStackNavigation.js

```
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack'
import PropertyScreen from '../../iOS/iPhone/screens/Properties/PropertyScreen'
import CarouselScreen from '../../iOS/iPhone/screens/Properties/CarouselScreen'
import MakeAnOfferScreen from '../../iOS/iPhone/screens/Properties/MakeAnOfferScreen'
import PropertiesScreen from '../../iOS/iPhone/screens/Properties/PropertiesScreen'

const StackNav = createStackNavigator();

const PropertiesStackNavigation = () => {
  return (
    <StackNav.Navigator initialRouteName='PropertiesScreen' screenOptions={{headerShown: false}}>
      <StackNav.Screen name="PropertiesScreen" component={PropertiesScreen}/>
      <StackNav.Screen name="PropertyScreen" component={PropertyScreen}/>
      <StackNav.Screen name="CarouselScreen" component={CarouselScreen}/>
      <StackNav.Screen name="MakeOfferScreen" component={MakeAnOfferScreen} />
    </StackNav.Navigator>
  )
}

export default PropertiesStackNavigation
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "rippe",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.21.0",
    "@ptomasroos/react-native-multi-slider": "^2.2.2",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.17.11",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.8",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.7",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.17",
    "axios": "^1.4.0",
    "expo": "~48.0.18",
    "expo-device": "~5.2.1",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.4",
    "firebase": "^10.1.0",
    "npx": "^10.2.2",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.71.8",
    "react-native-google-places-autocomplete": "^2.5.1",
    "react-native-maps": "1.3.2",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.5.0",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.20.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^10.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Here is a screenshot on the simluator and phone through expo

[image: Screenshot from expo on phone]

Comment: Do you get better logs if you remove LogBox.ignoreAllLogs()?

Comment: Hi, 

Please use firebase crashlytics for find the actual crash details. So we can investigate more detail.